# How to deploy to Glassfish v3.1.2 das using Jenkins Deploy Plugin?

Tags: glassfish-3, jenkins-plugins

I'm I using the plugin correctly?

I have a war which deploys fine to tomcat but when I try to deploy it to glassfish it throws the exceptions below. Its probably important to note that I'm running Jenkins on the same glassfish instance as I'm trying to deploy to locally.

I'm using the deploy plugin with the following settings:

war/ear file: **/daf-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
context: daf
container: Glassfish 3.x
GlassFish admin port: 4848
GlassFish hostname: 127.0.0.1

I have added a comment to JIRA here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11030?focusedCommentId=179452#comment-179452

```
    [#|2013-05-31T11:46:32.180-0400|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|hudson.model.AbstractBuild|_ThreadID=105;_ThreadName=Executor #1 for master : executing daf-deploy-master #3;|Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot communicate with the server
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:126)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:802)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:774)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:724)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1600)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.TargetException: Error getting required modules
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:313)
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getRunningModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:200)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.findTargetModule(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:350)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:122)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.deployapi.TargetImpl cannot be cast to org.glassfish.deployapi.TargetImpl
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:300)
... 19 more
javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.TargetException: Error getting required modules
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:313)
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getRunningModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:200)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.findTargetModule(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:350)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:122)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:802)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:774)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:724)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1600)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.deployapi.TargetImpl cannot be cast to org.glassfish.deployapi.TargetImpl
at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getModules(SunDeploymentManager.java:300)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Hi - as far as I can tell the Jenkins-cargo-whatever deploy plugin just does not work for Glassfish. I've been trying to use it to deploy to a remote glassfish instance - same problem. If it is on the same server, try doing it with a [shell script](http://florent.clairambault.fr/deploying-your-maven-web-apps-on-glassfish-with-jenkins)

Comment: Are Jenkins & Glassfish on the same machine ? If no, did you enable Glassfish secure admin ? It is needed for remote deployment